# Fortran: multiplication with matrices only containing +1 and -1 as entries

Tags: vector, matrix, fortran, multiplication

What would be an efficient way (in terms of CPU-time and/or memory requirements) of multiplying, in fortran9x, an arbitrary M x N matrix, say A, only containing +1 and -1 as its entries (and fully populated!), with an arbitrary (dense) N-dimensional vector, v?

Many thanks, 
Osmo

P.S. The size of A (i.e., M and N) is not known at the compilation time.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it would be faster to just do the multiplication instead of trying to avoid the multiplication by checking the sign of the matrix element and adding/subtracting accordingly. Hence, just use a general optimized matrix-vector multiply routine. E.g. xGEMV from BLAS.

Comment: Janneb, thanks. After having tried to come up with a 'clever' solution myself I had kinda concluded the same. I'm now wondering if it would matter if the matrix A were known in advance? To provide a context, suppose A - in the intended application generally large but 'skinny', say (10^4 up to 10^6) x (2 up to 12) - was generated (in Matlab notation) as A = sign(randn(1e5,6)) (A needs to possess a 'random' character) and is used, but not (re-)generated, repeatedly in an iterative algorithm.

Comment: wouldn't that be a xGEMV routine instead?

Comment: Steabert, thanks for the comment. You're right, the blas2 routine xGEMV would generally be preferable for performing an 'optimized' matrix-vector product. What I'd like to come after, however, is if some advantage would be possible from the special structure of the matrix (only +1 and -1 as entries), possibly assuming the 'full' knowledge of A 'in advance' (perhaps a 'silly' idea, but I'm wondering if in that case 'precompiling' (a part of) matvec computation would be possible, and if positive, would it lead to anything efficient, at least in terms of computational time). Thanks again.

Comment: @Osmo Bajric - Does the matrix have any other special characteristic (symmetrical maybe or something like that)? Matrix full of zeros can be taken as a special case, but +1s and -1s are just numbers; I'm not familiar with any functions that treat those as a special case. To a computer +1 and +3 are the same thing.

Comment: Rook, thanks for joining. No, the matrix has in general no special structure/characteristic besides being populated, in a (quasi-)random way, with +1 and -1 (for 'robustness'/convenience required in certain powerful but still not broadly known linear iterative solvers like, e.g., ML(k)BiCGStab or IDR(s)). N.B. Just to avoid possible confusion, the skinny A here is not A from an A*x=b, but rather a (linearly independent) 'shadow' matrix in forming (certain) residual vectors in the iterative scheme (sign(randn(m,n) for m>>n generally produces a rather well conditioned matrix). Regards.

Comment: Just to make a(n) (important?) correction, the M x N matrix A in A*v (or (v'*A')', if that brings any improvement) for arbitrary vector N-dim vector N is such that M << N (i.e., A has much much less rows than columns and v is a large vector). Rgds.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the usage scenario, if you have to apply the same matrix multiple times, you might separate it into two parts, one with the positive entries and one with the negatives.
With this you can avoid the need for multiplications, however it would introduce an indirection, which might be more expensive then the multiplications.
Thus janneb's solution might be the most suitable.

Comment: Haraldkl, thanks for the comment. I (believe) I understand what you're saying. Still, I 'feel' something even more efficient that general Blas routines should be possible in this special case of A*v, where A is MxN with M<<N (N between 2 and 12), obtained with sign(randn(M,N)) and v generally dense (v appears to be residuals from the N-dimensional space corresponding to the underlying to be solved linear system F*x=b. An idea just case into my mind and I'll try to work it out and will post my findings here (and at LinkedIn, although under my real name), unless the idea was not that promising.